# How to put description over a marker in google maps android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a map that places pin markers over certain locations. How do I place a description (Name and date) of the marker when you click on the individual pins? The description should hover over the pin and stay there until another pin is clicked or the same pin is clicked again. In my itemizedOverlay class I have

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
 //mOverlays is my array of overlayItems
  OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
//do stuff here

  return true;
}
```

But im not sure what to put in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

Comment: thanks, quick question, if I implement BalloonItemizedOverlay, does it still implement ItemizedOverlay?

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you knew how to make the balloons show above the marker if I'm using a pin and set public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {
   super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker), mapView);
   c = mapView.getContext();
  }

Comment: there should be an ontap method where the balloon is called to be displayed.

Comment: the problem is because i set bound center bottom, the bubble gets set bound center bottom as well, which is a problem, I would like to set it 30pixels above the marker

Comment: in the balloonitemizedoverlay constructor, there is a variable called viewoffset. make it greater than 0 and you should see the balloon placed at a higher position.